# CSS order rules question

Tags: css

Why the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/9EnuX/) results in red color rather than black ?

HTML:

```
<div class="error classA" att="A"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

[att=A].classA {
    background-color: red;
}

.error {
    background-color: black;
}
```

If I remove `[att=A]`, it becomes black, as expected. Why is that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in CSS, specificity counts towards the "Cascade" too.

`[att=A].classA` targets an attribute and a class name.

`.error` only targets a class name

Because the first is more specific, it gets applied over top of the second.

If you want to forcefully override a previously applied style, you can use the `!important` declaration:

```
[att=A].classA {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

However, I should note, IE <s>ignores the `!important` declaration</s>has [buggy support](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/importantdeclarations) for it, so use it with care.

Comment: Thanks for the "!important". I didn't know about that.

Comment: IE does not ignore `!important`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, nickf. My original source was outdated, and I haven't used it for awhile. I've fixed with a link to current support.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of [CSS Specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/). The 'red' rule is more specific (elements which have this attribute AND this class) than the 'black' rule (elements which have this class). When you remove the `[att=A]`, they have the same specificity, but because the black rule is later in the file, it wins.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know about specificity. I thought that always the last rule wins.

Answer (score 4):

The *most* specific selector wins, and `[att=A].classA` is more specific than `.error`.  Without it, the last one declared in the CSS wins, for example:

```
.error {
    background-color: black;
}
.classA {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Would also result in `red`.